# Sum If/Matching in excel

Tags: excel, match, sumifs

I have a trial balance with specific account numbers associated with each line item for the year 2014. I have the same account numbers in 2015 but they are in a different order.

I am updating a worksheet that is summing various combinations of numbers from the 2014 trial balance. I need to sum the same account numbers from the 2014 trial balance but using the 2015 trial balance, but since they are in a different order, I am having to tediously search for each individual account number and add each item to the sum function using ctrl since they aren't all directly in order.

Is there a way to search account numbers in column A of my 2015 trial balance for the the specific account numbers from column A of my 2014 trial balance and then when they do match, have them sum numbers in a corresponding column? For example

Column A 2014 Trial Balance (imagine these are vertical records)

```
1
2
3
4
5 
6 
7
8
9
10
```

Column A 2015 Trial Balance (imagine these are vertical records)

```
1
3
8
7
4
6
5
2
10
9
```

For each account number in column a there is a number I want to use in my sum functions in column c. so since numbers in column c with account numbers 1, 2, and 3 are  summed in 2014 I need to do this also for 2015 without searching through hundreds of records to find the account number. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a helper column using VLOOKUP or MATCH to see if each 2015 account number is in 2014, then SUMIF using the helper column with the amounts in column C, or with a single formula like this:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A10,'2014'!A1:A10,0))*C1:C10)
```